# child_process.spawnSync in Node.js (Typescript) does not work on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions

Currenly, I am developing VSCode extension working on Windows with Typescript. The expected result is as follows:

- One command prompt screen (shell) opens, performs all necessary steps in cmd file in the same screen and, when the commands are ended, deletes cache files when the window is closed by the user.
- when all tasks are ended, the window still opens.

---

Here is my code:

```
 const command = `cd ${cmdPath} && start /WAIT ${cmdfile} && exit`;
 const option = { shell: true, detached: true }
 child_process.spawnSync(command, option);
 if (isExistFile(cmdfile)) {
    fs.unlinkSync(cmdfile)
 }
 // something to be deleted...
```

This works only one time. This means that, when the user tried it again, nothing happened.

I thought the process which performs the command, "START", was left and added "exit" command, but in vain. I am not sure why this works only one time.

So, I tried another code as follows: (I changed "START" to "CALL".)

```
const command = `cd ${cmdPath} && call ${cmdfile} && exit`;
const option = { shell: true, detached: true }
child_process.spawnSync(command, option);
if (isExistFile(cmdfile)) {
   fs.unlinkSync(cmdfile)
}
// something to be deleted...
```

This code works almost perfectly, but does not meet the requirement that the screen keeps open.

I am wondering if I missed the option for child_process.spawnSync or command. Could you please help me?

Comment: If your wanting this all to be `sync`, why are you then creating a promise?

Comment: I am unfamilar with Typescript and Promise... I know I need to improve the code... ;-(